# Mann Kendall Trend Test in a multiband image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript

I'm trying to apply the Mann-Kendall trend test in an image with 35 bands each band referring to one specific year.

The image is for secondary forest in Brazil, so I have binary maps for each year (0, non forest; 1 forest). Looking like this:
[image]

So, I'm trying to adapt this tutorial (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/nonparametric-trends) to my case, however I'm not being very sucessful.
Since I don't have an ImageCollection, I'm trying to adapt it and apply to my image, but I don't have a deep knowledge in JavaSript so I'm quite not sure how I have to proceed.

I've tried this:

```js
//Join the time series for itself:`
var afterFilter = ee.Image().byte();
for (var i=0; i<35; i++)  {
    var y1 = 1985+i;
    var y2 = 1986+i;
    var i = 'classification_'+y1;
    var j = 'classification_'+y2;
    afterFilter = afterFilter.addBands(afterFilter);
}
var afterFilter = afterFilter.select(afterFilter.bandNames().slice(1));

var joined = ee.Image(ee.Join.saveAll('after').apply({
  primary: sforest_all,
  secondary: sforest_all,
  condition: afterFilter
}));


//Mann-Kendall Trend Test:

var sign = function(i, j) { // i and j are images
  return ee.Image(j).neq(i) // Zero case
      .multiply(ee.Image(j).subtract(i).clamp(-1, 1)).int();
};

var kendall = function (joined) {
  var afterCollection = ee.fromImages(joined.get('after'));
  return afterCollection.map(function (image) {
    // The unmask is to prevent accumulation of masked pixels that
    // result from the undefined case of when either current or image
    // is masked.  It won't affect the sum, since it's unmasked to zero.
    return ee.Image(sign(joined, image)).unmask(0);
  });  // Set parallelScale to avoid User memory limit exceeded.
}.flatten().reduce('sum');

var palette = ['red', 'white', 'green'];
// Stretch this as necessary.
Map.addLayer(kendall, {palette: palette}, 'kendall');
```

But keep getting an error:

> Line 91: (intermediate value).flatten is not a function

How can I do this? I've been stuck in these for a couple of days.
I even tried to to transform my image with multibands in an ImageCollection, but couldn't do that as well.

Here is the link for the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/3b38fd3272aecabdae1f4b3a5b0eed5e

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. All coding Questions here are expected to contain code as text, as a code snippet (minimal reprodicble code) in the body of the Question. Likewise, error messages should also be in text (making them searchable by others with the same issue).

Comment: Thank you! I have made the changes.